# Escape folder with spacing in command to be executed by cmd in Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

How to escape spacing in the following power shell script? I tried `, ^ and even double quotation enclosing folder name with spacing but still hit directory not exist. The execution stopped at with "C:\Users\Super:" directory not exist

```
cmd /c C:\Users\Super Human\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.5.1\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe -I C:\Users\Super Human\Desktop\School Service\School.Service.Student\Grpc\Protobuf\proto\exception\ -I ...
```

Comment: you must enclose the path with double quote : "C:\Your Path With Space"

Comment: hit the same error as well, i tried

Comment: and enclose all cmd : cmd /c ""  "C:\"   ""

Comment: hit 'C:\Users\Super' is not recognize as internal or external command. operable program or batch file

Comment: Excuse me i have missing another quote : cmd /c """C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe > "C:\Demo\New folder\log.txt"""" or cmd /c """"C:\Windows\System32\ipconfig.exe" > "C:\Demo\New folder\log.txt"""". Enclose all cmd /c parameters with three double quotes and , inside, enclose all path with one double quote. If your command line is executed by a powershell call, please put your powershell command here.

Comment: In powershell, you can type your path C:\ and then press CTRL+SPACE on your keyboard for intellisence autocompletion. It's can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately the intellisense doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Yes, but how to start your cmd /c exactly ? You use Start-Process ? with Start-Process it is easy to run a process: Start-Process 'C:\Users\Super Human\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.5.1\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe' -ArgumentList '-I','C:\Users\Super Human\Desktop\School Service\School.Service.Student\Grpc\Protobuf\proto\exception\','-I'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

```
$dq=$([char]34)
$CommandLine=-join (
    $dq,
    'C:\Users\Super Human\.nuget\packages\google.protobuf.tools\3.5.1\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe',
    $dq,
    ' -I ',
    $dq,
    'C:\Users\Super Human\Desktop\School Service\School.Service.Student\Grpc\Protobuf\proto\exception\',
    $dq,
    ' -I '
)
cmd.exe /c $CommandLine
```